# Simple JQuery doesn't work in Chrome ,FF works on IE6

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to JQuery, I do not know Why this simple JQuery does not work in Chrome ,FF and to my surprise works on IE6.
The simple idea is that when i click on the Div i should get an alert

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Page Chrome Test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <style  type="text/css">
      .divcls { width:100px; height:100px; background-color: black; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $(".divcls").click(function(e){
                 alert('Hi');
            });  
        })​
   </script>

   <div class="divcls">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works in Chrome v19.0.1084.46 m. Others can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2eDp/

Comment: Does it work if you use the URL http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js for your jQuery link? I believe the jQuery site prohibits hotlinking. Perhaps IE6 doesn't send the Referer header for scripts.

Comment: Try window.alert("hi") rather than just alert. Don't know why but sometimes explicitly calling alert this way works where alert does not.

Comment: scrappedcola, that makes no sense.

Comment: @@Interstellar actually it does because it finally worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to do invasive things like unintall/reintall FF,Chrome 
The suggestion of @@scrappedcola saved me.
so here is the code

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                   $(".divcls").click(function(e){
                     window.alert('Hi');
                   });  
                })​;
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, you're missing a semi-colon though at the end of the ready block:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zv3UJ/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".divcls").click(function(e){
     alert('Hi');
   });  
})​;
```